unable to deploy argocd application though deployment to k8s works fine using helm install command

Failed to load target state: failed to generate manifest for source 1 of 1: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Manifest generation error (cached): failed to set app instance tracking info on manifest: failed to set app instance label: failed to get labels from target object /v1, Kind=ConfigMap test/test-configmap: .metadata.labels accessor error: contains non-string value in the map under key "app":  is of the type , expected string

We are trying to setup argo cd on our k8s cluster. The application is successfully deployed using helm chart but when I am trying to deploy using argo cd its showing this
Tried checking using helm template command to check app labels is set.
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-configmap
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: dev-env
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: dev-env
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app: "test-configmap" # Added explicit app label`

